# Double pane vinyl windows -compromised seal -can it be fixed?

Tags: insulation, windows

While I was doing exterior washing for our windows using a pressure washer (low pressure settings) I notices   that one of the windows got water in between the glass panes. 
The drops that got is went down on the glass and they left marks in what seems to be very fine dust that deposited there in time.

What options do I have to fix this window?

Comment: If it was a gas filled window replacement is the only way I know of.

Comment: Nothing against that if they can match the color which I am afraid they won't because of its patina. Would they (a specialized shop) be able to do it reusing the existing vinyl frame?

Comment: Some manufactures can. I have not found any shops (glass shops) that do repairs in my area only Payne replacements from the OEM.